# Count users from multiple tables in the same dataset

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I have the following four data tables in the same dataset at **Google Bigquery**:

[image]

I need to count users from these four tables, and organize the information into a table like this:

[image]

The following query returns the `<projectID>:<dataset>.<tableID>` path of all existing tables at this moment:

```
SELECT CONCAT(project_id, ':', dataset_id, '.', table_id) AS paths, 
FROM [<projectID>:<dataset>.__TABLES__] 
WHERE MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(creation_time)  < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 0, 'DAY')
```

How to iterate the counting in Google Bigquery for all previous paths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wildcard tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/wildcard-tables) should do the trick by pulling out the `_TABLE_SUFFIX` reserved column e.g.

```
#standardsql
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS lazy_count,
  _TABLE_SUFFIX AS table
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.*`
GROUP BY
  table
```

[image]

**Note**: I'm not sure what you are counting, so I've just used a lazy `COUNT(*)`. You could simply change this to whatever column you need.

Comment: thanks for your answer. how transalte it into legacy sql? I try to use TABLE_QUERY() wildcard function.

Comment: Why do you want to use legacy? It's not recommended to use it any more.

Comment: Because all my queries are written into legacy sql, and I have no time to migrate all code. Could I combine both queries?   #legacySQL SELECT.... FROM .....  #standardSQL SELECT.... FROM....

Comment: But that should stop you writing your new queries (like this one) in standard SQL, right? Sorry, but I don't know how to do this in legacy sql.

Comment: I'm trying to migrate legacy sql. How to select automatically the previous closest Sunday in standard Sql? Do you know? Something like this: SELECT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) DAY) as five_days_ago

Comment: From this link https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators I know that DATE_SUB() function doesn't support DAYOFWEEK(). Another option?